# How get value from text file in linux

Tags: linux, file, search

I have some file xxx.conf in text format. I have some text "disablelog = 1" in this file.
When I use

```
grep -r "disablelog" oscam.conf
```

output is

```
disablelog = 1
```

But i need only value 1.
Do you have some idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need it as a var in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISABLELOG=$(awk -F= '/^.*disablelog/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' /path/to/oscam.conf)
echo $DISABLELOG
```

When calling this script, the output should be 1.

Edit: No matter wether there is whitespace or not between the equals sign and the value, the above will handle that. The regex should be anchored in either way to improve performance.

Answer (score 4):

one way is to use `awk` to print just the value

```
grep -r "disablelog" oscam.conf | awk '{print $3}'
```

you could also use `sed` to replace `diablelog =` with empty

```
grep -r 'disablelog' oscam.conf | sed -e 's/disablelog = //'
```

If you also want to get the lines with or without space before and after `=` use

```
grep -r 'disablelog' oscam.conf | sed 's/disablelog\s*=\s*//'
```

above command will also match

```
disablelog=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
grep -r "disablelog" oscam.conf | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Which would return the string `' 1'` (note the whitespace). Besides that, a better option would be `awk -F= '/^disablelog/{print $2}' oscam.conf`, saving a process and a pipe and making use of awk's build in pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun a solution without `awk`

```
grep -r disablelog | cut -d= -f2 | xargs
```

`xargs` is used here to trim the whitespace