# How to go to directory with value from text file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script in bash file.

```
TplFolder=$(awk -F= '/^.*directory/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' /path/to/oscam.conf)
cd $TplFolder
```

I control output for this

```
 TplFolder=$(awk -F= '/^.*directory/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' /path/to/oscam.conf)
```

output throught "echo $TplFolder" is OK

```
/etc/tuxbox/config/
```

but for "cd" not working

```
 cd $TplFolder
```

output is "can't cd to /etc/tuxbox/config/"

do you have some other idea please?

### EDIT

Whole script which works

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Variable tmp folder

```
TempFolder="/var/volatile/tmp"
```

get directory from config file oscam.conf. In config file is line httptpl = /etc/tuxbox/config/tpl

```
OscamTplFolder=$(grep -r httptpl /etc/tuxbox/config/oscam.conf | cut -d= -f2 | xargs)
```

Variable for download file

```
TrunkUrl="http://www.streamboard.tv/svn/oscam-addons/oscam-template/Envi_template/branches/compressed_files/Envi_Template.tgz"
```

Go to temp folder and delete file

```
cd $TempFolder
[ -f Envi_Template.tgz ] && rm -f Envi_Template.tgz
```

Download file and move from temp folder to folder in oscam.conf - /etc/tuxbox/config/tpl

```
wget -q $TrunkUrl
[ -f Envi_Template.tgz ] && mv -f Envi_Template.tgz $OscamTplFolder
```

Go to folder /etc/tuxbox/config/tpl and remove some file

```
cd $OscamTplFolder
[ -f CSS.tpl ] && rm -f CSS.tpl
[ -f FOOTER.tpl ] && rm -f FOOTER.tpl
[ -f HEADERSHORT.tpl ] && rm -f HEADERSHORT.tpl
```

Decompress

```
tar -xzvf Envi_Template.tgz
rm -if Envi_Template.tgz || exit 1
#done all OK
exit 0
```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: Can _you_ cd to `/etc/tuxbox/config/`? Does the user that's running the script have permission to that directory?

Comment: Is that the actual error message from the script? That's not an error format I'm used to seeing from bash.

Comment: No, /etc/tuxbox/config/ is in config file oscam.conf in line "directory=/etc/tuxbox/config/". My preview question is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976359/how-get-value-from-text-file-in-linux/26978060#26978060 and works perfect. But tag "cd"not working.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Nice spot. Can't reproduce this, either. SELinux?

Comment: @skyndas: When you issue `cd /etc/tuxbox/config` on the console, what is returned then?

Comment: @skyndas Yes, that directory may well be in the config file, but does it actually exist? What happens when you run the command yourself?

Comment: @skyndas Please check your file for carriage returns. See Step 1 in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @Markus I use this "OscamTplFolder=$(awk -F= '/^.*httptpl/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' /etc/tuxbox/config/oscam.conf)" and "echo $OscamTplFolder" is /etc/tuxbox/config/tpl/

Comment: @arco444: Directory "/etc/tuxbox/config/tpl/" exist. Command cd /etc/tuxbox/config/tpl/ is OK.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I use telnet for working with my receiver Vu+. Vu+ have enigma.

Comment: @skyndas: I have _absolutely_ no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: it does not matter. I tested "wget -q $TrunkUrl
[ -f Envi_Template.tgz ] && mv -f Envi_Template.tgz $OscamTplFolder" and file Envi_Template.tgz is copying to /etc/tuxbox/config/tpl. Problem is only for cd $OscamTplFolder.

Comment: Finish: I use "grep -r httptpl /etc/tuxbox/config/oscam.conf | cut -d= -f2 | xargs" to get directory from config file and now is all OK. VERY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

I can not imagine any other reason than your variable "$OscamTplFolder" contains some extra characters like \r. Please check

hexdump -C <<< "$OscamTplFolder"