# how to replace substring in file without newlines in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line, ubuntu-18.04

I have a config file template which I intend to use in the creation of a bash script to automate a installation task, the file has something like this (`config.conf`):

```
...
bootstrap_servers => "HUB_NAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
...
```

Also I get variables from another file which has something like this (`vars.conf`):

```
...
HUB_NAMESPACE:aNamespace
...
```

I want to replace `HUB_NAMESPACE` in `config.conf`. If I make the replacement using the following (there are several `HUB_NAMESPACE` to be replaced in the file):

```
HUB_NAMESPACE=$(awk -F: '/^.*HUB_NAMESPACE/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' vars.conf)
sed -i 's^HUB_NAMESPACE^$HUB_NAMESPACE^g' config.conf
```

The resulting file will be something like this:

```
...
bootstrap_servers => "aNamespace
.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
...
```

Which causes the app to crash due to the newline between `aNamespace` and `.servicebus.windows.net:9093"`.

Is there a way of preventing the insertion of the newline after replacing this way? Is there a better or simpler solution to replace substrings in a file?

Used commands extracted from here:

[How get value from text file in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26976611/9991694)

[How to use sed to find and replace text in files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/)

Also tried:

[Remove newline from unix variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57128)

[Using sed's append/change/insert without a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059200/9991694)

Comment: tldr, but shell variables does not expand in single quotes, that's what you have now,  try changing single quotes to double quotes, at your `sed` code

Comment: After fixing the single quotes in the `sed` command, I cannot reproduce the OP's phenomenon because the *trailing newline characters are removed* in the command substitution `$(command)`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your command and it worked perfectly without any newline but in sed replace single quotes with double quotes.

```
HUB_NAMESPACE="$(awk -F: '/^.*HUB_NAMESPACE/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);print $2}' vars.conf)"

sed -i "s^HUB_NAMESPACE^$HUB_NAMESPACE^g" config.conf
```

Still if you are having problem then try below solution:
A simple one liner that uses sed and awk without explicitely defining variable and with in-place file editing

```
sed -i "s/HUB_NAMESPACE/"$(awk -F: '/^.*HUB_NAMESPACE/{gsub(/ /,"",$2);printf "%s", $2}' vars.conf)"/g" config.conf
```

Output:

```
cat config.conf    
...
 bootstrap_servers => "aNamespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093" 
...
```

The newline insertion is prevented by using printf instead of print